# response.status always 200

Tags: javascript, request, httprequest, httpresponse

in my code I want to check if my get request was successful:

```
.then(function (response) {
        if (response.status === 200) {
            console.log("ok")
        }
        else{
            console.log("not ok")
        }
```

even though it says 302 on the network tab it is always printing "ok" (console.log(response.status) also says 200). Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

check request readystate and use == instead of ===

```
then(function (response) {
        if (response.status == 200 && response.readyState == 4) {
            console.log("ok")
        }
        else{
            console.log("not ok")
        }
```